# Как правильно слушать смену location.hash без рутеров с реактом?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, роутинг

Допустим , я хочу при переходе на `/#1337` получить `1337` пост в блоге.

У меня это получилось сделать так

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import _ from 'lodash'
import first from 'lodash/first'
import axios from 'axios'
import Sidebar from './components/sidebar'
import Post from './components/post'

if (!location.hash){
    location.hash = 1;
}
window.onhashchange = function(){
ReactDOM.render(<div><Sidebar/><Post id={location.hash.slice(1) || 1  }/></div> , document.querySelector('#app'));
};
```

Но оно открывается только когда хэш сменен через ссылку на сайте.

Конечно можно сделать так:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import _ from 'lodash'
import first from 'lodash/first'
import axios from 'axios'
import Sidebar from './components/sidebar'
import Post from './components/post'

if (!location.hash){
    location.hash = 1;
}
window.onhashchange = function(){
ReactDOM.render(<div><Sidebar/><Post id={location.hash.slice(1) || 1  }/></div> , document.querySelector('#app'));
};
ReactDOM.render(<div><Sidebar/><Post id={location.hash.slice(1) || 1  }/></div> , document.querySelector('#app'));
```

Но это какой то говнокод.

Ну и что делать?

Comment: А почему вы не хотите использовать роутер ?

Comment: Чтобы не писать один и тот же код два раза - надо вынести его в функцию и вызывать ее.

Comment: Виктор, потому что у меня паранойя на эту хрень.

Comment: Павлу спасибо))